# Why does the column name banner from GetType() not display each time

Tags: powershell

In the output, the header line of column names from Get_Type() displays only once. Why is that? Is there anything I can do to make it display in the output of GetType() every time?

```
PS C:\src\ps> Get-Content .\mva.ps1
$items = "Doug", "Finke", "NY", "NY", 10017
$FirstName, $LastName, $Rest = $items

$FirstName
$FirstName.GetType()
"==============================="
$LastName
$LastName.GetType()
"==============================="
$Rest
$Rest.GetType()
"==============================="
```

The output.

```
PS C:\src\ps> .\mva.ps1
Doug

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
===============================
Finke
True     True     String                                   System.Object
===============================
NY
NY
10017
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
===============================
PS C:\src\ps> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      0      10586  494
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass values to Format-Table (ft):

```
Get-Content .\mva.ps1
$items = "Doug", "Finke", "NY", "NY", 10017
$FirstName, $LastName, $Rest = $items

$FirstName;
$FirstName.GetType() | ft;
"==============================="
$LastName;
$LastName.GetType() | ft;
"==============================="
$Rest;
$Rest.GetType() | ft;
"==============================="
```

Answer (score 0):

[Paweł Dyl beat me to a similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38774650/3905079) but I want to expand on it a bit.

The PowerShell formatter looks at the first object it sees and decides how to display the output based on that type.

To work around that, you have to decide what you actually want to do.

First, understand that by default the output of that code is being sent down the pipeline, the equivalent of sending it all to `Write-Output`. If this is in a function for example, all of that data will be the return value (but NOT the headers / formatted information, that comes about after the function returns if nothing else is done with the data).

So if you use `Format-Table` as suggested, it will look correct, but you've fundamentally changed what's happening. In a function, you would be returning format objects; a very different thing. Another thing to note is that this will always show a table format, even if the default format would have been a list.

You could also pipe to `Out-String`, which would give you a string representation of the default format, but again you're returning a different thing: a formatted string.

You can pipe to `Out-Host` and this will work too, but critically, this information will **not** be returned to your pipeline (from the function), but it will be displayed on the screen.

So just consider what you really want and how the various options affect that.

Comment: When the output pipeline contained a `System.Reflection.TypeInfo`, something decided to write the header lines. When the subsequent `System.Reflection.TypeInfo` objects appear, the header lines are not written out. Why the first time and not the others?

Comment: I am still interested to know why the headers came out the first time and not the others.